# How can we easily update our own vendor in symfony?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I have a symfony project.
I have a bundle in my vendor directory. This bundle belongs to me. The bundle is hosted in our own server (git).
This bundle is constantly evolving.

My question is :
Is it possible to update this bundle inside my symfony project ?
I tried but I don't know how to push the updated code...

For the moment, I am obliged to import the bundle in a new project, do the update, commit and push, and finally do the "composer update" in symdony project.
It is a bit complicated.

Do you have another way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with composer alone.  You can specify your dependencies to come directly from a branch in your git repository.  Example below uses github, but you should be able to use your git server instead:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/username/repository"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "username/repository": "dev-branch_name"
    }

}
```

Then you can just do your edits inside of the bundle's repository, commit, push, and just run `composer update` to pull your changes in to your current project.

Comment: This will still not eliminate the necessary `composer update` step. Also, working with branches is unstable, because a branch name can theoretically point to ANY commit in the repository, not just the working ones. Using tags is highly recommended for production quality software.

Comment: Yes, you can use tags rather than a branch name too, but I don't see how you can get around the `composer update` step. If it's a composer package, and it needs updating, you will need to run that command. If you don't want to run that command, then you will still need to load that repository somewhere else in your code base and run a `git pull` whenever you update the code. How is that any different?